# Why is my real time clock getting the wrong time from my PC?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, time

I want my real-time clock to set its time as the time on my PC. However, when I run the following sketch, the real-time clock reports the time as being 32-33 seconds earlier than my PC says the time is.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 RTC;

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Wire.begin();
  RTC.begin();

  if (! RTC.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
// following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
// uncomment it & upload to set the time, date and start run the RTC!
    RTC.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }
}

void loop () {
  DateTime now = RTC.now();
  Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.println();
}
```

I have also tried manually setting the time on the RTC, but I end up with the same problem: the RTC is always 32-33 seconds behind what I set it to. The lag happens as soon as I run the sketch. It seems very odd to me that no matter how I try to set the time, I end up with exactly the same error. I can tell the Arduino to report the time as being 33 seconds after what the RTC says it is, but this solution seems kind of sketchy, and I am worried that something is fundamentally wrong with my RTC or the way I am using it.

I am using an Arduino Uno with an Assembled Data Logging Shield from Adafruit. The data logging shield uses a DS1307 RTC. Has anyone had this problem before, or have any ideas about what could be causing it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ive taken Hugo Bertini and Oli explanation to use in my projects and it works ! Thank you (: but it goes faster by 26 seconds....

Answer (score 17):

The `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are set when the code is compiling so they will naturally be behind since the code still needs to finish compiling and then be flashed to the chip.

See the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/time) for an example of how to sync it to your computer over serial.

> TimeSerial.pde shows Arduino as a clock without external hardware.
>
> It is synchronized by time messages sent over the serial port.   A
>   companion Processing sketch will automatically provide these messages 
>   if it is running and connected to the Arduino serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the offset by calling once the following code in the `setup()` function:

```
RTC_DS3231 rtc;

DateTime now = rtc.now();
rtc.adjust(DateTime(now.unixtime() + 10)); // add 10s to current time for fixing the offset
```

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing a similar problem with an Arduino UNO and a Nano. Both from the same PC.
 Indeed it looks like the time it takes from compile time to upload + MCU start is reflected.

Assuming the RTC has a good battery and the compilation + upload times are consistent, then adding a drift compensation to the code seems to do the trick.
Here's how I did it (in my case 7 seconds did the "trick" - sorry for the hardocode, but that's for mere description purposes):

```
RTC.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
DateTime t = DateTime(RTC.now().unixtime()+7);
RTC.adjust(t);
```

Regards,
Hugo Bertini

Answer (score 0):

With the <DS1307RTC.h> library the DS1307 can be adjusted during time setup, by using a global variable and then adding this to Sec reading in the getTime() function, for example as follows:

```
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
tmElements_t tm;
byte adjustt = 8;  // adustment for seconds lag allowing for compiler download time

/*********************

bool getTime(const char *str) {
  int Hour, Min, Sec;
  if (sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &Hour, &Min, &Sec) != 3) return false;
  tm.Hour = Hour;
  tm.Minute = Min;
  tm.Second = Sec + adjustt;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Arduino takes the computer time and sends it to the DS1307. The time it takes to copy is the one you are seeing wrong. I would solve the problem by advancing the computer time the necessary seconds that you say is delayed and when programming you should have the exact time.